# How to convert javascript function calls which accept functions as arguments into coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I have some javascript that looks like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

How would I convert this to coffeescript?

Comment: The link posted by richoffrails says that your code should compile http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24('button').on%20'click'%2C%20(e)%20-%3E%0A%20%20alert%20%24(%40).text()

Comment: bah!!! okay, sorry for wasting everyone's time. I just realized I was not editing the right file. My code was working from the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could express this in CoffeeScript as:

```
$('button').on 'click', (e) ->
  alert $(@).text()
```

The [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) website has a great "Try CoffeeScript" feature that shows you the output JS. Here's an [example](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%24%28%27button%27%29.on%20%27click%27%2C%20%28e%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20alert%20%24%28%40%29.text%28%29) of your code.

Comment: Yes it is, this compiles to `$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  return alert(this.text);
});` It's missing the `$` and the method call after `text`

Comment: Sorry fixed :) Updated link and code. Pasted in old code and link by accident.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the compiler you're using is out of date since [this page](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%24%28%27button%27%29.on%20%27click%27,%20%28e%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20alert%20%24%28@%29.text%28%29) shows that

```
$ ->
  $('#network_select select').on 'change', (e)->
    alert $(@).val()
```

Should compile into

```
$(function() {
  return $('#network_select select').on('change', function(e) {
    return alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Which does have the argument to your change handler. If the compiler is not the problem, then you are missing something in your question.